# How to find the timestamp in a table that closest with a timestamp in another table(MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I have two tables Fuel and DrivingTime. Fuel have accountID, deviceID, timestamp, fuelLevel, address. DrivingTime have startTime, stopTime. My goal is to show all fields in Fuel if timestamp match with startTime or stopTime. I wrote the query like that:

```
SELECT F.deviceID, F.timestamp, F.fuelLevel,F.address
FROM Fuel F, DrivingTime DT
where (F.timestamp = DT.stopTime or F.timestamp = DT.startTime)
and F.accountID = 'something1' and F.deviceID = 'something2';
```

Unfortunately, I found that It isn't any timestamp in Fuel match with startTime in DrivingTime, only F.timestamp = DT.stopTime return true. After searched google I can match timestamp with startTime and stopTime separately, however I confused of matching them together. Here is the code:

```
select from_unixtime(F.timestamp), F.fuelLevel, F.address
from gtse.tblFuel F, gtse.tblDrivingTime DT
where DT.stopTime = F.timestamp and F.accountID = 'vinhnghia'
and F.deviceID = '14C-00027'
```

and here:

```
select from_unixtime(F.timestamp), F.fuelLevel, F.address
from gtse.tblFuel F, gtse.tblDrivingTime D
where D.accountID = 'vinhnghia' and D.deviceID = '14C-00027'
and F.timestamp between D.startTime and D.startTime + '60'
order by
abs(F.timestamp - D.startTime) asc limit 1
```

. So how can I match two of above code in only one query?

Comment: you need to use a join between the two with a timestampdiff function

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT DT.startTime, DT.stopTime, F.deviceID, F.timestamp, F.fuelLevel, F.address
  FROM Fuel F
  JOIN DrivingTime ON F.timestamp <= DT.stopTime + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
                  AND F.timestamp >= DT.startTme - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
 WHERE /* whatever criteria */
```

This will locate all the rows of your `Fuel` table that are between the start and stop times of rows in your `DrivingTime` table. It will show the start and stop times. I have added a fuzz factor of one minute to cover for possible slight inaccuracies in time stamps.

To find the `DrivingTime` row with the closest start time to each row in `Fuel`, you're going to first need to summarize that result set as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(DT.startTime) AS firstFuelTime,
       F.deviceID, F.timestamp, F.fuelLevel, F.address
  FROM Fuel F
  JOIN DrivingTime ON F.timestamp <= DT.stopTime + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
                  AND F.timestamp >= DT.startTme - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
 WHERE /* whatever criteria */
 GROUP BY F.deviceID, F.timestamp, F.fuelLevel, F.address
```

This will find the first (in time) startTime in DrivingTime for each row in `Fuel`.

**Edit**. If you want the timestamp closest to the stop time, you can easily add that to the SELECT clause, as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(DT.startTime) AS firstFuelTime,
       MAX(DT.stopTime) AS lastFuelTime,
       F.deviceID, F.timestamp, F.fuelLevel, F.address
  FROM Fuel F
  JOIN DrivingTime ON F.timestamp <= DT.stopTime + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
                  AND F.timestamp >= DT.startTme - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
 WHERE /* whatever criteria */
 GROUP BY F.deviceID, F.timestamp, F.fuelLevel, F.address
```

Comment: I only expected to get two timestamp that equal(or closest) startTime and stopTime, because startTime may at 6.am and stopTime may 10.am while timestamp in Fuel return each two minutes. So from so many timestamp in table, I have to chose timestamp at 6.am and 10.am

Comment: Is the query still true if I have a series of startTime and stopTime record for example:(6.am-10.am)(1.pm-3p.pm),(5.pm-6.pm),etc? and I have to match timestamp with each couple of time above. I tried your suggestion but no result return.